# Admob, AdSense address request new Pin not working

Tags: admob

I have integrated AdMob into my app. I have also reached threshold for address verification.

[image]

I have wait for almost 4 week and never received any mail for PIN verification. I check back the address and found missing my block number. I process to update to address but don't see any button or preference to request new PIN. I check on both AdMob and AdSense address verification but seem no button also. How can we verified our address (request new pin...)?

### Updated

Form suggestion I come to this page but don't know how to proceed: https://support.google.com/admob/troubleshooter/6069070?hl=en#ts=6077344

[image]

Comment: saw similar post- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41264476/above-one-month-but-still-not-receiving-adsense-address-verification-pin . Looks like impacting multiple users. Please raise query with google

Comment: thanks for your help. do you know how can we raise query? I have been in waiting time for almost a month

Comment: yes. Click on Help icon on top right on your apps.admob.com page. Click on email option from dropdown and select Mail Pin and submit your information

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. i use your suggestion and come to the page (updated in question) but don't know how to proceed. there is now button there